# Solidity 0.6.x - when is it mandatory to use assembly (with examples)?

Tags: solidity, assembly

Solidity's development is very active and, if compared to several other codes, stable releases are updated quite frequently. Which cases need assembly as mandatory feature for Solidity release 0.6.x? Examples, i.e. from recently deployed contracts, are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

On [readthedocs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.0/assembly.html#example) are some example use cases for when using assembly is mandatory or it makes the execution more efficient. For example, the only way to load the compiled code of another contract into a bytes variable is by using the `mload` operation in assembly.